# Client Synchronization on JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

How can I develop a test, using JMeter, where two clients can connect in a single TCP Server?

In my test I will have, two Client and One Server:

```
Client 1          Server        Client 2
   |       M1       |              |
T1 |--------------->|       M1'    |
T2 |                |------------->|
T3 |                |       R2     |
T4 |       R2'      |<-------------|
T5 |<---------------|              |
```

The Client 1, send the message `M1` to the server, the server process that message and send it to the Client 2. The client 2 answer the message. I want to check the time of Response from `T1` to `T5`.

1. I'm implementing my client connection using `Java Request`. Is there any JMeter feature to Synchronize Actions between threads?
2. Or should I implement my own threads inside my `Java Request` class?
3. If I implement my own Threads, this mean that I will duplicate my Threads for test. How many threads a single instance of JMeter support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>1. JMeter's threads (virtual users) are absolutely independent and know nothing about what others are doing. However you can use [Inter-Thread Communication](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter) plugin to add some extra logic and implement [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

 2. I don't think you should as JMeter will not be measuring these extra threads
 3. You're limited only by your hardware/software. Assuming you follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) you should be able to kick off several thousands of threads on a modern PC. In any case there is always possibility to run JMeter test in [distributed mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)</strike>

---

Just in case there are [TCP Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler) and [HTTP Raw Request Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/), both are capable of firing TCP requests so it might be the case you will not have to reinvent the wheel.

If you want to start 2 different Samplers at the same time you can put them under [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller), this guy isn't a part of standard JMeter distribution, you will need to install it using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager).

Comment: I have already look *TCP Sampler* and *HTTP Raw Request Sampler*. The server I'm testing use a bit level protocol, not only text over TCP. The best approach is use the protocol library.

Comment: With **Inter-Thread Communication** I can only change data between two Threads, There is any way two execute two Samplers in parallel? Started by the same Thread Group

Comment: The easiest is going for [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer)

Comment: Synchronizing Timer will not solve the problem. It onlys synchronize the request start..

Comment: Apologies for misunderstanding, if you want to start 2 different Samplers at the same time you can put them under [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller), this guy isn't a part of standard JMeter distribution, you will need to install it using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager).

Comment: This is a possible solution! :)